# WAR file is deployed but works incorrectly on GlassFish

Tags: javascript, grails, glassfish

I have a grails app (grails-2.4.4). I make a war file with **grails war** command. War file structure:

```
1. /css
    ...
2. /images
    ...
3. /js
    /prototype
        ....
    application.js
4. META-INF
    ...
5. WEB-INF
    ...
```

I can succesfully deploy the war on GlassFish4 and run the app. But the **index** page is displayed incorrectly, because there is no **prototype** folder (and its js files) in resources of the page. Just **application.js**.

Comment: Did you install the prototype-plugin for Grails?

Comment: No, I didn't. Your advice was right, thanks!

Comment: I have now posted this as an answer, so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed the **prototype-plugin** for Grails.

From the Grails [plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/prototype):

> As of Grails 2.0 Prototype is no longer the default JavaScript library
>   (jQuery is used instead). This plugin allows older application to
>   continue to use Prototype by uninstalling the jQuery plugin and
>   installing this one.
>
> See https://github.com/gpc/grails-prototype for the source and usage
>   information